# How to handle json date format pass in web api input request

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

When I pass birth date in jsondate format inside the input request then in controller request objects sets to null automatically.

Please find the below input body from postman -

[image]

Please find the below screenshots from controller -

[image]

and when i pass birthdate in "yyyy-mm-dd" format then request object contains value

[image]

[image]

**can someone help me with how to handle jsondate case**

Comment: It's simple, don't pass date like the first one, the api won't understand the format you are sending, just pass it like the second way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue before when using `MicrosoftDataFormat`.

You can fix the issue by installing the package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` .

And use it like below.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```